# How to translate subset finding recursion into a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, recursion

I have a function that recursively goes through some list of numbers and finds all its subsets that are divisible by some divisor. Is there any possible way to translate it into a loop solution?

```
def subset_sums(arr, l, r, dvr, summed = False, summ = 0): 

    d_count = 0

    if summed and summ % dvr == 0:
        d_count = 1

    if (l > r):
        return d_count

    d_count += subset_sums(arr, l + 1, r, dvr, True, summ + arr[l])
    d_count += subset_sums(arr, l + 1, r, dvr, False, summ) 

    return d_count
```

Comment: 3 guys disliked my question but didn't even bother to read it at the firstplace. I'm not trying to get a solution. Just get some fresh ideas cause I'm actually stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an explicit stack for keeping intermediate solutions:

```
stack = []
stack.add((l, r, False, 0))

while stack:
    cur_state = stack[-1]
    stack.pop()

    # doing something useful, updating sums and indices, checking necessary conditions
    stack.add((updated_l, updated_r, updated_summed, updated_sum))
```

This mimics recursion, but keeps everything at memory heap and does not depend on a stack's size.